# Как установить конкретное количество символов в SQL?

Tags: sql, constraints

Всем привет. Изучаю SQL, а именно - создание таблиц.
Как установить ограничение на числовое поле, я информацию нашёл, получилось:

rating – рейтинг, вещественное число. Принимает положительные значения от 0 до 10.
rating FLOAT,
CHECK (0 <= rating <= 10).

а вот что делать с символами, пока не понимаю. Может быть вы подскажете? Только без наворотов, пожалуйста))

country – страна фильма. Символьное поле, содержащее ровно 2 символа.

Comment: *Символьное поле, содержащее ровно 2 символа.* `CHAR(2) NOT NULL`

Comment: + в разных СУБД свои строковые типы и наверное вам стоит как раз определиться с СУБД вначале и почитать внимательно про типы данных

Comment: check (length (country)=2)

Comment: @0xdb Не подойдёт. Если использовать CHAR(2), то на любое NOT NULL значение вернётся 2. И VARCHAR(2) не поможет, если пробел введён как часть значения, а не добавлен как заполнитель. А если поле не объявить NOT NULL - то и NULL тоже пройдёт эту проверку. Так что и необходимо NOT NULL, и в твой CHECK нужно добавить TRIM(). PS. С другой стороны, задание предполагает, что пробел - легитимный и значащий символ. Ибо в задании никаких ограничений в этом смысле не имеется.

Comment: @Akina Ну вот я попробовал и ваш метод. Вставляю в поле не 2, а 1 символ, не бьёт никакой ошибки, хотя должно, насколько я понимаю...

Comment: *не бьёт никакой ошибки, хотя должно, насколько я понимаю...* - ну где-то не так сделал, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (2 = LENGTH(TRIM(country_code)))
)
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('AA')
```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A')
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('AAA')
```

> ```
> Data too long for column 'country_code' at row 1
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A ')
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (' A')
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('')
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'test_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (NULL)
```

> ```
> Column 'country_code' cannot be null
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-2rzpHoz)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать тип данных CHAR или VARCHAR (в зависимости от требований) и указать максимальное количество символов в скобках.
Пример для поля "country" с ровно 2 символами:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    -- Другие поля таблицы...

    country CHAR(2)
);
```

В данном случае, CHAR(2) означает, что поле "country" будет содержать ровно 2 символа.

Если тебе нужно установить максимальное количество символов (а не фиксированное), то попробуй VARCHAR:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    -- Другие поля таблицы...

    country VARCHAR(2)
);
```

поле "country" с типом VARCHAR(2) может содержать до 2 символов, один тоже.

Comment: *Пример для поля "country" с ровно 2 символами* Вот ввожу я `'X'`. Поле принимает его, преобразуя в легитимное двухсимвольное `'X '` - явно не то, что хотел бы автор.

Comment: просто написать char(2) я изначально пробовал, читал о типах данных. Но в задании РОВНО 2 символа, а такой код прекрасно работает и с одним, без ошибки. Мне просто интересно, как это реализуется на практике, каким ограничением